# How do i run a function that is nested between two setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript

> Write a function called solution that takes in 2 parameters, a number
> and a function.
>
> solution should execute the input function (which returns a number)
> after first input parameter milliseconds. The input function should be
> run again after waiting the returned number of millisecond

I tried to do it this way but it doesnt work

```
 const solution = (a,fun) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let b=fun();

    setTimeout(() => {
      fun();
    }, b*1000)
  }, a * 1000)
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
> node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -o --watch
 FAIL  js1/__tests__/12.js
  call functions
    × Function should only run twice (5 ms)

  ● call functions › Function should only run twice

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      16 |     // runtime 50ms
      17 |     jest.advanceTimersByTime(50);
    > 18 |     expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                    ^
      19 |
      20 |     // runtime 100ms
      21 |     jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);

      at Object.<anonymous> (js1/__tests__/12.js:18:20)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? We can't figure out what's wrong and help if we don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @AniketG sorry, i edited my question with the error message

Comment: The function does what is described, as far as I can tell. It's hard to debug it further without the the source code that failing test. Can you post that?

Comment: @AlexWayne its alright, your solution worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as is, but it doesn't fulfill the instructions.

> after waiting the returned number of ***milliseconds***

You are treating the numbers as seconds, and then multiplying them by `1000` to convert them to milliseconds.

So remove the `* 1000` math and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Ohh, i was supposed to edit a. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question asks to run it after specific milliseconds but you are multiplying it with 1000 making it run after seconds instead; Removing the 1000 should fix this:

```js
const solution = (a,fun) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
    let b=fun();

    setTimeout(() => {
      fun();
    }, b);
  }, a);
}

solution(1000, () => {
  console.log("Hello");
  return 2000;
});
```